# Show different Views based on conditions on button click in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, custom-view

I have a `ViewController`their is a button at top right side. When i click that button i want to `Show/Hide` a `UIView` at bottom with size half of `ViewController`on same `ViewController` . Anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show what you have already tried.

Comment: @PGDev  till now nothing i have tried i m begineer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only `Show/Hide a UIView` is your requirement, below code will work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var viewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var customView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.viewHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.height / 2
    }

    @IBAction func onShowHideButtonPress(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.customView.isHidden = !self.customView.isHidden
    }
}
```

**Storyboard:**

[image]

Comment: this i know but i want to call view controller in that area @PGDv

Comment: You can use a Container View instead of the simple UIView for that. I have updated the answer. Have a look.

Comment: it is the same answer @PGDev

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Please elaborate with some screenshot or anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157268/discussion-between-anuj-and-pgdev).